# Parse rss feed and append string to link - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I'm working on a project that parses an rss feed for each article's title, description and link. I need to then append the link with a string @"?f=m"
I'm having trouble figuring out where to start. I'm new to IOS programming. I think the file I need to manipulate is here:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

RSSItem* item = (RSSItem*)self.detailItem;
self.title = item.title;
webView.delegate = self;

NSURLRequest* articleRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: item.link];


webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webView loadRequest: articleRequest];
}
```

But it could also be here:

```
-(void)fetchRssWithURL:(NSURL*)url complete:(RSSLoaderCompleteBlock)c
{


dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    //work in the background
    RXMLElement *rss = [RXMLElement elementFromURL: url];
    RXMLElement* title = [[rss child:@"channel"] child:@"title"];
    NSArray* items = [[rss child:@"channel"] children:@"item"];

    NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:items.count];

    //more code
    for (RXMLElement *e in items) {

        //iterate over the articles
        RSSItem* item = [[RSSItem alloc] init];
        item.title = [[e child:@"title"] text];
        item.description = [[e child:@"description"] text];
        item.link = [NSURL URLWithString: [[e child:@"link" ] text ]] ;
        [result addObject: item];
    }

    c([title text], result);
});

}
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: It works :) I sincerely appreciate your help. Many, many thanks.

Comment: I'd vote this up if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply append the parameter as below:

```
NSString *modifiedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[item.link absoluteString],@"?f=m"];
NSURL *modifiedUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:modifiedString];
```

Now use modifiedUrl instead of **item.link**

Comment: Since you are appending a string literal, why use `stringWithFormat:`? Why not simply use `NSString *modifiedString = [[item.link absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:@"?f=m"];`.

Comment: @rmaddy: thx maddy. you can also use that. but i normally using this method and i couldnt find any huge difference between them.

Comment: It works. Just remember that `stringWithFormat:` is much less efficient than simple string appending. For one line like this it doesn't really matter. The other option would be to replace the second `%@` in the format with the actual text since it is a literal.

Comment: Thanks very much all, I sincerely appreciate your help. Great learning experience.